# Can't get proper location state in React Router if location is added in Routes component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, framer-motion

I'm working with Framer Motion and React Router so I added `location={location}` in `<Routes>`. When I try to get `location.state.from` it just shows me the path that I am redirected to and not the previous path. When I remove `location` in `<Routes>` then it works properly.

**App.js**

```
<AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
  <Routes key={location.pathname} location={location}>
    <Route element={<PublicWrapper />}>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Route>

    <Route element={<PrivateWrapper />}>
      <Route path="/tracker" element={<Tracker />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</AnimatePresence>
```

**Login.js**

```
const location = useLocation();
const from = location.state?.from?.pathname;
console.log(from); // Returns '/login' even if user came from '/tracker'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by getting the path inside `PrivateWrapper` component instead of `Login` component.

**PrivateWrapper.js**

```js
const location = useLocation();
const { setFrom } = useContext(AuthContext);

useEffect(() => {
  setFrom(location.state.from.pathname);
}, [location.state, setFrom]);
```